# Transform entry of column if it matches a criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column (departments) in my table that has 4 different values: (department1, department2, department3 or department4). What I would like to do is transform the text to something else depending on a criteria to make it easier to understand.

So very simply put:

```
IF departments = "department1" then re-write department1 as Finance
IF departments = "department2" then re-write department2 as HR
IF departments = "department3" then re-write department2 as Service
etc...
```

Then the departments column would go from looking like this:

```
departments
-----------
department1
department1
department3
department1
etc..
```

to

```
departments
-----------
Finance
Finance
Service
Finance
etc..
```

I've been searching for a long time now and couldn't find any way to do it, I'm not even sure if it's possible at all. Apologies if this has been asked before.

Comment: Obvious solution: Create a table with two columns - department_id and name which contains a pair of (department_id, title) (example: (department1, Finance), (department3, Service), and inner join using this translation table.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I don't have rights to add data.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to select the data in that format then do this

```
select 
case when departments = 'department1' then 'Finance'
     when departments = 'department2' then 'HR'
     when departments = 'department3' then 'Service'
     when departments = 'department4' then '4th dept'
end
from table_name
```

if you want to update the table

```
UPDATE table_name
SET     departments =  
    case when departments = 'department1' then 'Finance'
         when departments = 'department2' then 'HR'
         when departments = 'department3' then 'Service'
         when departments = 'department4' then '4th dept'
    end
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfect! Thank you for the answer. So simple and I couldn't figure it out. Learned something new today at least, thanks again!

Comment: @Mischa glad it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update data in-place, a simple

```
update mytable set departments = 'Finance' where departments = 'department1'
```

If you want to leave data as it is and only change what the `select` statement returns, use [case](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html):

```
select
  case departments
    when 'department1' then 'Finance'
```

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple solution and I couldn't figure it out! Works exactly how I want it.